# How to make CSS menu bar activated only after my mouse cursor is at the menu.

Tags: css

```
<div id='cssmenu'>
 <ul>
    <li class='active '><a href='index.html'><span>Home</span></a></li>

   <li><a href='#'><span>About</span></a></li>
      <li class='has-sub '><a href='#'><span>Contact Us</span></a>
      <ul>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Contact 1</span></a></li>
         <li><a href='#'><span>Contact 2</span></a></li>
      </ul>
   </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

I want this `"HOME"` keep inactive just like `"ABOUT"` and `"CONTACT US"` if I didn't touch it by my cursor.

I want each one of them to be activated and turn to blue after my cursor goes exactly at the menu.

Please Help :)
Thank You.

Comment: i want to send the picture of the menu bar...but i cant ..so sorry...not enough reputations.

Comment: have you heard about `hover` selector in css? http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

Comment: add a link to some example of what you mean

Comment: http://cssmenumaker.com/menu/blue-tabbed-drop-down?menu=055
i download it from here...hover? i know about it ..but i dont how to do it by myself.

Comment: @chovy http://jsfiddle.net/srgYF/ hope u can see more clearly here

Comment: im so sorry about my attitude @loler,, i just want to know about that hover..and i dont know how to setting that hover..because inside my cssmenu code..too many hover inside it.its confusing.

Comment: YES...i get it now...thank you. need to take time to understand this hover ...once again..thank you all..u guys really helpfull :) :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every class you need to use

```
a {
   //any styles
     color:gray;
  }
a:hover
  {
   //any styles
     color:blue;
  }
a:visited
  {
   //any styles
  }
```

**for ex:**

active a
      {

```
  }
```

active a:hover
      {
      }
   active a:visited
      {
      }

Answer (score 0):

There are three selectors for `<a>` tag:

```
a:link    {}
a:visited {}
a:active  {}
```

You can make all of them same style and on hover `a:hover` make different style. try [example on w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_sel_link_more1).

> The **`:link`** selector is used to select unvisited links.
>   The **`:visited`** selector is used to select visited links.
>   A link becomes **`active`** when you click on it. The **`:hover`** selector
>   is used to select elements when you mouse over them. And it's used not only for `<a>` tag.

take a look at [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fvYzV/).

Comment: ok ok ..i try it by myself now..i will repost here if anythhing happen..Thank You :)

Comment: YES...i get it now...thank you. need to take time to understand this hover ...once again..thank you all..u guys really helpfull :) :) :)